# How many languages are available in the Ubuntu distributions?

Tags: language-support, internationalization, translation

Do you know if there are statistics on how many languages Ubuntu supports (completely translated / partially translated)?

I've tried the following command:

```
apt-cache search language-pack | grep "base" | grep -v "GNOME" | grep -v "KDE" | grep -v "inkscape" | wc -l
```

which returned 140 results. But, I guess many of the translations are only partially done and not very good. So how do I find out more about high quality translations?

Answer (score 2):

As of [Ubuntu 10.04](http://people.ubuntu.com/~dpm/ubuntu-10.04-translation-stats.html), Ubuntu had 28 fully translated languages and a total of 218 supported languages.

You may have more luck digging into the [Ubuntu translation pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations). I haven't been able to find an update on the data provided in the first link.

It looks like you can get a raw export of the translation coverage on 12.10(Quantal)[here](http://people.canonical.com/~dpm/data/ubuntu-l10n/) along with some instructions on the [Ubuntu Translations Statistics page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/Stats). There is a web app to present/interpret the data, but I have not used it.