# Fully translated languages

Tags: language-support

How many languages are available for Ubuntu distributions? (such as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr)

I am looking for something like this:
http://people.ubuntu.com/~dpm/ubuntu-10.04-translation-stats.html

Referenced here:
[How many languages are available in the Ubuntu distributions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229828/how-many-languages-are-available-in-the-ubuntu-distributions)

- (29) Fully Supported
- (218) Total Languages

Unfortunately, the above is only for 10.04.4 LTS (Lucid Lynx) - support ended 2013-05-09

[Apparently](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop), Ubuntu is now "Fully translated into over 40 languages..." but...

1. which 40 fully translated languages?
2. which / how many others?
3. what is the completion status of the others?

Is it really necessary to use a web app to interpret raw data to get this information as suggested in the previous post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+translations
- Click "View all languages"
- Click "Status" to have the entries sorted by completion rate